# action at input field doesn't work with type command

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

The input field:

```
<div class="unit col-md-12">
<label class="ng-binding">Title</label>
<input class="form-control ng-valid ng-dirty" type="text" maxlength="50" ng-model="FormBuilderModel.Form.Name" placeholder="" ng-disabled="LoadingPanel.Load ">
</div>
```

The effected field:

```
<h3 class="form-heading" ng-click="SelectForm()">
<input class="ng-pristine ng-valid" type="text" maxlength="50" ng-model="FormBuilderModel.Form.Name" placeholder="Form Name" ng-disabled="LoadingPanel.Load ">
</h3>
```

---

The Case:

- Typing in the first field affect the second field.
- Using Selenium IDE command "Type" to type a title in the first field don't affect the second field.

Please help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Just set //input[@class="form-control ng-valid ng-dirty"] as a selector and should work

Answer (score 0):

I've found with Angular input fields that sendKeys works better than type.